# Node.js Global variable sometimes = 1 and sometimes = 0, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, global

**QUESTION:**

My web app is running on the Google Cloud App Engine. There are currently 2 VM instances running for that App Engine website .

Strangely enough, when a specific event is called (about 10 times in a minute), it seems there are 2 different instances of a specific global variable.

I say this because sometimes length of my global array is 0 and sometimes it is 1 when in effect it hasn't changed.

What may cause this ?

**CODE:**

app.js

```
global.accountsArray = [];
```

file1.js

```
global.accountsArray.push(account);
```

file2.js

```
eventEmitter.on('event', function (body) {
    console.log("EMITTER");
    //sometimes prints out 1, sometimes prints out 0
    console.log("Array length: "+global.accountsArray.length);
    //
    console.log("DESTINATION: "+body.block.destination);
    //sometimes empty, sometimes not
    console.log("ARRAY :"+global.accountsArray);
    //
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What may cause this ?**

The variable `accountsArray` being in memory. Any restart to your process or vm, will reset the variable. Consider using a store for resilient persistance like redis or memcache.

**EDIT**:

Should have mentioned, another cause would be because the variable lives in memory per each VM, there is no common storage, so you would have odd results. Again, this problem is solved by using a common session storage both VMs can use.

Comment: I have never used memcache or redis to my knowledge. Are those databases or an intermediary solution ?

Comment: key-value databases

Comment: Guess, I'll just have to store the var in my database :/ There must be a better solution.